# how to fix missing requirement while the deployment of an OSGI bundle

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, osgi

I am trying to deploy a simple OSGI bundle (hello world) in glassfish 4.1.1 but I got the following error:

```
Infos:   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle com.mycompany.MavenHelloServiceImpl [324]:
  Unable to resolve 324.0: missing requirement [324.0] 
    osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=com.mycompany.mavenhelloserviceapi)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
```

I don't know how to fix the missing package , I already defined "com.mycompany.mavenhelloserviceapi" as a dependency in the bundle MavenHelloServiceImpl and it is present in the dependencies folder in the bundle MavenHelloServiceImpl 
Any idea how to fix this error ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having `com.mycompany.mavenhelloserviceapi` as a dependency in your pom.xml is not enough : the pom is about compile-time dependencies. you see here an issue about a runtime dependency missing.

You should install `com.mycompany.mavenhelloserviceapi` in your container.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the project that contains `com.mycompany.mavenhelloserviceapi` as a bundle project and explicitly export this package. now deploy this bundle alongwith your hello world bundle.

Alternatively ,you can use [Pax Wrap](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol) to deploy the jar that contains `com.mycompany.mavenhelloserviceapi` to glassfish without modifying the project.